# Castle Windsor - registration by convention

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a project that uses `Castle Windsor` for a DI container.

Initially it was a small project so I have been registering each class individually, however the project is now growing so I would like to register by convention, however I am finding documentation difficult to apply to my situation.

Without going into too much detail I have a project which contains the interfaces each one following a naming convention such as `IUserService.cs` or `IBuildingService.cs`.

I then have another project which contains the implementations sticking to a similar convention `UserService.cs` or `BuildingSevice.cs`

At the moment that required two separate calls to `Kernel.Register`.

I know it is possible to register by convention, I am just not familiar with the syntax - anyone able to offer some guidance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Castle Windsor: How to register by convention with delegate method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309416/castle-windsor-how-to-register-by-convention-with-delegate-method)

Comment: Not really a duplication because his interfaces/classes have no common interface.

Comment: @5NRF - Did it solve it for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly() 
    .WithService.DefaultInterfaces());
```

*If the implementations don't sit in the same assembly as the registration code then use on of the other "FromAssembly" methods*

[Castle's documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md#defaultinterfaces) is quite good :)

Comment: Slight change in that you need to do .FromThisAssembly().InNamespace().WithService...

Other than that exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Good to here :) I left the InNamespace out because didn't want to confuse with maybe not essential stuff. Glad it worked!

Comment: Yeah, sent me down the right path, I was getting a bit mixed up - so simple in the end!
Thanks again!